# R: ggvis - HTML function - failing to "add_tooltip()"

Tags: r, ggvis

this is a basic question about ggvis. I've googled, but still...

I want that, when someone hovers over a specific date (2014-12-05), the tooltip will show: **3,188 sessions** (please, notice the comma).On so on for everyday on the data frame.

Have this df:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:31, .Label = c("2014-12-01", 
"2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-04", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-06", 
"2014-12-07", "2014-12-08", "2014-12-09", "2014-12-10", "2014-12-11", 
"2014-12-12", "2014-12-13", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", 
"2014-12-17", "2014-12-18", "2014-12-19", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-21", 
"2014-12-22", "2014-12-23", "2014-12-24", "2014-12-25", "2014-12-26", 
"2014-12-27", "2014-12-28", "2014-12-29", "2014-12-30", "2014-12-31"
), class = "factor"), sessions = c(1932L, 1828L, 2349L, 8192L, 
3188L, 3277L, 2846L, 2541L, 5434L, 4290L, 2059L, 2080L, 2111L, 
3776L, 1989L, 1844L, 3641L, 1283L, 1362L, 1568L, 2882L, 1212L, 
957L, 851L, 928L, 1435L, 1115L, 1471L, 1128L, 1022L, 768L), id = 1:31), .Names = c("date", 
"sessions", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And i need to get a Google Analytics look for sessions:

[image]

1) Want to plot a path graph, with a tool tip for every single day.
2) In the X Label, just want to plot the first date, the middle date, and the last date. See my code for my failed attempt.

My code:

```
EvolucionVisitas <- EvolucionVisitas %>% ggvis(~date, ~sessions) %>%
  add_tooltip(~sessions,"hover") %>%
  layer_paths()
```

**I've read the help page, but i don't understand well the arguments. What is the html function?**

The error says:

```
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: could not find function "html"
observe({
    value <- session$input[[id]]
    if (is.null(value)) 
        return()
    if (!is.list(value$data)) 
        return()
    df <- value$data
    class(df) <- "data.frame"
    attr(df, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(1L)
    fun(data = df, location = list(x = value$pagex, y = value$pagey), 
        session = session)
})
```

---

**How to show in the X label just the first, middle, and last dates?

After, @LyzandeR answer, i got what i needed, and added "Sessions: " to the tool tip. But have problems with the X label:

-This is my attempt to show just the first, middle, and last dates of the data frame:

```
EvolucionVisitas %>% ggvis(x= ~date, y= ~sessions, key := ~id) %>%
  layer_points()  %>%
  add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover") %>%
  layer_paths() %>%
  add_axis("x",
           value=c(EvolucionVisitas$date[1], EvolucionVisitas$date[round(length(EvolucionVisitas$date)/2,0)],
                   tail(EvolucionVisitas$date, n=1)),
           properties=axis_props(
             labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with a tool tip for every single day" - can you clarify this please?

Comment: @nrussell, Sure, it is a list of sessions by day. I want if i hover over "2014-12-05" to show: 3,188 sessions (pls notice the "," comma). And so on for every single day. I'll copy this to the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation of `?add_tooltip` you will see that the second argument needs to be a function and thus this is what you need to provide in the following way:

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='   date        sessions
2014-12-01      1932
2014-12-02      1828
2014-12-03      2349
2014-12-04      8192
2014-12-05      3188
2014-12-06      3277
2014-12-07      2846
2014-12-08      2541')
```

**Solution**

First of all you need to provide an id so that `ggvis` will know how to link the columns. I do this with the `id` column below:

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Then you need to create the function `mysessions` to enter into `add_toolbox`:

```
mysessions <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  #notice below the id column is how ggvis can understand which session to show 
  row <- df[df$id == x$id, ]
  #prettyNum shows the number with thousand-comma separator  
  paste0(prettyNum(row$sessions, big.mark=",",scientific=F)) 
}
```

And this is how you write the function. Notice the `key` below:

```
library(ggvis)
df %>% ggvis(x= ~date, y= ~sessions, key := ~id) %>%
  layer_points()  %>%
  add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover") %>%
  layer_paths()
```

Notice that `add_tooltip` does not work properly with `layer_paths` so you need to add a `layer_paths` on top of `layer_points`. The tooltip will work with `layer_points`.

I cannot show you everything here but here is a snapshot of how it shows when I hover my mouse pointer over the 3rd point:

[image]

Comment: thanks, that's a very good explanation. I manage myself to paste "Sessions: " to the actual number. How ever, i've problems with the "x" label. I'm looking for something like google analytics, where u see only few dates, but as you hover, you can see every date point. Don't know is its necessary to open a new question, or you may help me here? Thanks. I'll edit my question, to show my attemp.

Comment: @LyzanderR i also notice that, sometimes when hovering over, i see bad info in the tool tip: for example the infor for 2014-12-01, when hovering in 2014-12-07, but hovering again fix it...one or more times... Is this a limitation on the package? Thanks again.

Comment: HI Omar. Thanks for the comments and your good words.  For your first comment you probably need to open a new question because I don't know at the moment. I think it might be possible but I cannot answer without researching. Probably best to ask it in a new question. For the second question the problem is that if you hover above the line (i.e. not over the bullets) you will see the first value of  the table i.e. 1932. This is a limitation I m afraid, and it happens because `add_toolbox` only works correctly with `layer_points`. Early days for `ggvis` I m afraid :)